# Joining on multiple fields in a NHibernate Criteria query

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a `Dept` table and a `Emp` table.

I need to join these two table in such a way that the `where` clause looks something like this:

```
where dept.deptId = emp.DeptId and dept.deptName = emp.empTrainingName
```

I tried this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dept.class).createAlias("empMap","id");
```

Using this, the first where condition i.e. `dept.deptId = emp.DeptId` is performed. But I am not sure how to compare `dept.deptName` with `emp.empTrainingName`.

How do I do this using the Criteria API in NHibernate?

Answer (score 9):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dept.class, "department")
                           .createAlias("empMap", "employee")
                           .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("department.deptName", 
                                                        "employee.empTrainingName"));
```

You may also use a with clause, which would be necessary in case of a left join:

```
Criteria criteria = 
    session.createCriteria(Dept.class, "department")
           .createAlias("empMap", 
                        "employee", 
                        Criteria.LEFT_JOIN,
                        Restrictions.eqProperty("department.deptName", 
                                                "employee.empTrainingName"));
```

Side note: your choices of names are awful. Instead of `Dept.deptId`, Why not use `Department.id`? Instead of `Emp.empTrainingName`, why not choose `Employee.trainingName`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes they are awful, i was thinking how to explain my problem and did not have a real table name, hence came out with something meaningless. BTW, in this way, i am performing inner join between tables. If i want to perform outer join, then how to do it using hibernate? Can you please post some sample example for outer join which i can play around with?