# Hibernate: how can I specify left condition?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, conditional-statements, criteria

I've two tables:

- The table A named "Prova" has the following columns: id, id_comitato, id_comitato_erog
- The table B named "comitato" has the following columns: id_comitato, name

Criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = mySession.createCriteria(Prova.class, "p");
criteria.createCriteria("comitato", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Translate this query in SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM Prova p LEFT JOIN comitato c ON p.id_comitato=c.id_comitato
```

But what I want is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Prova p LEFT JOIN comitato c ON p.id_comitato_erog=c.id_comitato
```

How can I specify this join condition?

Thank you very much,
have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this -> [Yet another post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967695/joining-on-multiple-fields-in-a-nhibernate-criteria-query)
.Basically you would have to do something similar to the following:

```
Criteria criteria = 
mySession.createCriteria(Prova.class, "p")
       .createAlias("comitato", 
                    "c", 
                    Criteria.LEFT_JOIN,
                    Restrictions.eqProperty("p.id_comitato_erog", 
                                            "e.id_comitato"));
```

Comment: @yardrimz thank u very much..I've adopted the other solution of the link and it works!

Comment: @yardrimz Oh no, it doesn't work :( In this way the query is: SELECT * FROM Prova p LEFT JOIN comitato c ON p.id_comitato=c.id_comitato where p.id_comitato_erog=c.id_comitato

Comment: OK! I've resolved! I missed the @JoinColumn with id_comitato_erog in the java class..now works! thank you!

Comment: @smanulla you're welcome, glad you've managed to resolve your issue.