# How to join three tables using FluentNhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm using FluentNhibernate for my C# application i would like to know how to join three tables which not having Foreign keys defined. Lets assume i have following table structure,

**Student [StudentID, Name1, Name2, ClassID ]**

**Class [ClassID, Name, SchoolID]**

**School [SchoolID, SchoolName]**

I need to join above three tables like this

```
SELECT a.Name1,a.Name2,b.Name,c.SchoolName FROM Student a, Class b, School c WHERE a.ClassID = b.ClassID AND b.SchoolID = c.SchoolID
```

I have following class structure for ORM

```
public class Student
{
        public virtual int      StudentID { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name2 { get; set; }
        public virtual int      ClassID  { get; set; }
 }



 public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
    {
        public StudentMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.StudentID ).Column("student_id");
            Map(x => x.Name1 ).Column("name_1");
            Map(x => x.Name1 ).Column("name_2");
            Map(x => x.ClassID).Column("class_Id");
            Table("student");
        }
    }





public class Classt
{
        public virtual int      ClassID { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int      SchoolID  { get; set; }
 }



 public class ClassMap : ClassMap<Class>
    {
        public ClassMap ()
        {
            Id(x => x.ClassID ).Column("class_id");
            Map(x => x.Name ).Column("name");
            Map(x => x.SchoolID).Column("school_Id");
            Table("class");
        }
    }




public class School
{
        public virtual int      SchooID { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name { get; set; }
 }



 public class SchoolMap : ClassMap<School>
    {
        public SchoolMap ()
        {
            Id(x => x.ClassID ).Column("class_id");
            Map(x => x.Name ).Column("name");
            Table("school");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you have no realation between your entities? whats the point of using ORM if won't use any relation between objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should go something like this;

```
public class Student
{
        public virtual int      StudentID { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name2 { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Class> ClassList  { get; set; }
}

public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.StudentID ).Column("student_id");
        Map(x => x.Name1 ).Column("name_1");
        Map(x => x.Name1 ).Column("name_2");
        HasMany(x => x.Class).KeyColumn("ClassId")
        Table("student");
    }
}

public class Class
{
        public virtual int      ClassID { get; set; }
        public virtual string   Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Student> StudentList { get; set; }
        public virtual School School  { get; set; }
}

public class ClassMap : ClassMap<Class>
{
    public ClassMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.ClassID ).Column("class_id");
        Map(x => x.Name ).Column("name");
        HasMany(x => x.Student).KeyColumn("StudentId")
        References(x => x.School)
        Table("class");
    }
}

public class School
{
    public virtual int      SchoolID { get; set; }
    public virtual string   Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Class> ClassList { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolMap : ClassMap<School>
{
    public SchoolMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.SchoolID ).Column("SchoolId");
        Map(x => x.Name ).Column("name");
        HasMany(x => x.ClassList).KeyColumn("ClassId")
        Table("school");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mert, and how is the query looks like, ?

Comment: what are you trying to achive, nhibernate works object oriented. what is your returning object?

Comment: I mean if i want to get specific student object, i get like this `code`var user = session.CreateCriteria<Student>("st").Add(Restrictions.Eq("st.StudentId", login)).UniqueResult<Student>();`code` Like that how can i execute below join in FluentNhibernate with your suggested file structure                                                                                    `code`SELECT a.Name1,a.Name2,b.Name,c.SchoolName FROM Student a, Class b, School c WHERE a.ClassID = b.ClassID AND b.SchoolID = c.SchoolID `code`

Comment: Hi Mert, I finally came up with following solution but it always returns single object, i need to return object List please let me know if you know the answer  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7asuz47siuqh28/NHibernate.cs?dl=0

Comment: I believe your join mapping causes this, remove it and try again It should get all students.

Comment: I used two "join"s to map three tables. which Join should i need to change?

Comment: I am not expert but I don't think you need to use join there at all. Why don't you use joins in criteria?

Comment: Please let me know how to use joins in the criteria

Comment: you can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967695/joining-on-multiple-fields-in-a-nhibernate-criteria-query